# Return Observable<Song> from an object of SongResponse that contains a List<Song>

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, rx-android

I have a class `SongResponse`:

```
public class SongResponse implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("token")
    public String token;

    @SerializedName("items")
    public List<Song> songList;
}

@GET("songs")
Observable<SongResponse> getSongs(@Query("token") String token)
```

In the manager class, I want to return an `Observable` by used the request above

```
public Observable<Song> syncSongs(token) {

    return mSongService.getSongs(token);
        ....

        @Override
        public Observable<Song> call(List<Song> songs) {
            return mDatabaseHelper.setSongs(songs);
        }

}
```

`syncSongs` will call another `Observer` to insert songs in the database.

I used RxAndroid 2. I try to find about `.map` and `.flatMapIterable`, but don't result my problem. Could you help me complete this function?

Comment: Do you want to return a Observable<Song> for each song of the list or for a specified one ?

Comment: Yes, for each song of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
public Observable syncSongs(token) {
    return mSongService.getSongs(token).flatMap(new Function<SongResponse, ObservableSource<List<Song>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<List<Song>> apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull SongResponse songResponse) throws Exception {
            return Observable.just(songResponse.getSongList()); //some changes here
        }
    }).flatMapIterable(new Function<List<Song>, Iterable<? extends Song>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<? extends Song> apply(List<Song> songs) throws Exception {
            return songs;
        }
    }).flatMap(new Function<Song, Observable<Song>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Song> apply(final Song song) throws Exception {
            return Observable.just(song);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Cochi, but there existe errors, i forgot that Observable<SongResponse> getSong() return Observable<SongResponse>, not of Song

Comment: Can you get the list of song from `SongResponse` ?

Comment: I try this code but it still doesn't work, but thanks anyway

Comment: What are the issues ?

Comment: There is a incompatible type error in the return of first flatMap(new Function<SongResponse, )...

Comment: I made some changes .

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cochi, it really work. I just change a little bit by unusing flatMapIterable. I can't increase your point but please receive from me 100 points. You really save my time.